# hide and animate when mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i want my div to hide when mouseover and turn animate instade and when mouserout div return.
so i did some thing like this.

```
<div class="tec">
    <span class="html5"><img ng-src="../images/Technologies/HTML5.png" alt="html5"  /></span>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".html5").mouseover(function(){
        $(".html5").hide(500);
        $(".html5").addclass(".htmlanimate");
        });
    });
    $(".html5").mouseout(function(){
        $(".html5").addclass(".html5");
    });
</script>
```

so far i can only hide - every thing else not working =/

**CSS**

```
.htmlanimate {
    -webkit-animation-name: html5animate;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera / -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; / Chrome, Safari, Opera / -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3; / Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: html5animate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}
@-webkit-keyframes html5animate {
    0% {
        border-left:10px solid red;
    }
    25% {
        border-top:10px solid red;
    }
    50% {
        border-right:10px solid red;
    }
    100% {
        border-bottom:10px solid red;
    }
}
```

Comment: animate:
.htmlanimate{
  -webkit-animation-name: html5animate; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: html5animate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    
}
@-webkit-keyframes html5animate {
    0%   {border-left:10px solid red;}
    25%  {border-top:10px solid red;}
    50%  {border-right:10px solid red;}
    100% {border-bottom:10px solid red;}
}

Comment: .htmlanimate{
  -webkit-animation-name: html5animate; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: html5animate;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    
}
@-webkit-keyframes html5animate {
    0%   {border-left:10px solid red;}
    25%  {border-top:10px solid red;}
    50%  {border-right:10px solid red;}
    100% {border-bottom:10px solid red;}
}

Comment: OK, Are you specifying image width and height in your CSS?

Comment: This line in mouseout makes no sense `$(".html5").addclass(".html5");` you're giving the element the class it already has

Comment: Also, jQuery functions are case sensitive, it's addClass, not addclass.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you, if i understood you better:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8c2gxhj/2/)

```js
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;

$(".html5").hover(function(){
 $(".html5").css("height", height + "px");
 $(".html5").css("width", width + "px");
    $(".html5").addClass("htmlanimate");
    $("#imageid").fadeOut(500);
    
}, function(){
    $("#imageid").fadeIn(500);
 $(".html5").removeClass("htmlanimate");
});
```

```css
.html5
{
   display:inline-block;
   border:10px solid transparent;
}
.htmlanimate {
    -webkit-animation-name: html5animate;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera / -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; / Chrome, Safari, Opera / -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3; / Chrome, Safari, Opera */

    animation: html5animate 5s infinite;  
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}
@-webkit-keyframes html5animate {
    0%, 25% {
        border-left:10px solid red;
    }
    25%,50%,74%  {        
        border-left:10px solid red;
        border-top:10px solid red;
    }
    75% {        
        border-left:10px solid red;
        border-top:10px solid red;
        border-right:10px solid red;
    }
    100% {        
        border-left:10px solid red;
        border-top:10px solid red;
        border-right:10px solid red;
        border-bottom:10px solid red;
    }   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tec">
    <span class="html5">
        <img id="imageid" src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2015/googles-17th-birthday-6231962352091136-hp.png" alt="html5"  />
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i have like 5 images to do this

Comment: @amir cohen So all these 5 images are in `html5` div? Also are all these image with same dimensions(height & width)?

Comment: If that is the case. Check if you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brv1becw/). I will update for an Answer.

Comment: thats great! but my 5 imgs in 5 divs

Comment: Create a demo in my fiddle with 5 div as you want. Save and share me the link.